# Unable to update a transferred google play application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, keystore, google-play-console

We received a google play app through a transfer. I built a new app and wanted to place this build as an update on top of the old transferred app in order to retain users.

I have changed the applicationId to match the transferred app, versionCode increased, and versionName increased.

We did not initially receive the keystore but I do see "App signing key certificate" and the "Upload key certificate" under SETUP->APP INTEGRITY in Google play console inside the transferred app.

Is there a way I can sign and update this transferred app using these certificates or a different method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did they use Google App Signing or not?  If they used Google app signing, you can probably just contact Google, let them know the keystore is lost, and go through the process to upload a new one to them.

If they didn't use Google App Signing, you need to get their keystore.  There's no other way to allow people to download new versions, as the keystore must match the one on user's devices or they won't allow a new version to install.